# How to customize validation messages in Laravel?

Tags: validation, laravel

I searched a lot before asking this question but found nothing to help me. 
I started using Laravel as a PHP framework. As I started to do form validation, I used the `Validator` class to manage all my validation and error messages. But I'd like to know how I can customize the error messages (I'd like to put them in another language for example).

Comment: Start copying the file located at `app/lang/en/validation.php` to `app/lang/es/validation.php` for Spanish translation. Then change the default language with `App::setLocale('es');`.

Comment: ^ yep, this is one way to go..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation says](http://laravel.com/docs/localization#language-files):

> Language strings are stored in files within the `resources/lang` directory. Within this directory there should be a subdirectory for each language supported by the application.

Just create a directory with the supported language code, and add a `validation.php` file (it is wise to just copy the one provided in English then start translating).

An example for Spanish translation would be created at `resources/lang/es/validation.php`. And it will look as follow:

```php
<?php

return array(
    "required" => "El campo :attribute es requerido.",
);
```

After that, you will need to *change the default language*.

> The default language for your application is stored in the `app/config/app.php` configuration file. You may change the active language at any time using the `App::setLocale` method.

Example of changing the default language at runtime:

```php
App::setLocale('es');
```

Comment: It seems like they moved it from `app/lang...` to `ressources/lang...`

Answer (score 5):

in laravel 5 the validation.php file comes under the folder resources.

```
resources/lang/en/validation.php
```

Comment: And you can find [all the factory messages translated on GitHub](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang).